# how to set contol property in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Very simple and stupid question.

i have a page class

```
public partial class ProtectWayItem : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public int Count { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                 Count = 10;
        }
    }
```

and how i can set div id equal Count.

I mean something like:

```
<div id='<%# Count %>' > </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `= instead #`

```
<div id='<%= Count %>' >
```

And if you want to call with the `# sign` then you need to call a DataBind() method..

```
protected void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

here is what each expression means

- The <%= expressions are evaluated at
  render time
- The <%# expressions are evaluated at
  DataBind() time and are not evaluated
  at all if DataBind() is not called.
- <%# expressions can be used as
  properties in server-side controls.
  <%= expressions cannot.

For a better understanding, please check out this link: [The difference between <%= and <%# in ASP.NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2007/02/13/the-difference-between-lt-and-lt-in-asp-net.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id='<%= Count %>' > </div>
```

But you must remember this section must be in FORM section.

Comment: Sorry, Form is only in page, but you have only control.