# Call code behind method from aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have an image tag like

```
<asp:Image ID="ImgProduct" runat="server"    ImageUrl='<%# FormatImageUrl("10")%>' />
```

and in  code behind i have
a  method like

```
protected string FormatImageUrl(string s)
{
return "image"+s;
}
```

when i rum the code i am expecting that an HTML image tag with src="image10"
will render.

but nothing happens
why?
any clues?

i am in asp.net . not mvc

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989544/how-to-set-contol-property-in-asp-net/5989565#5989565

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the aspx page

```
<asp:Image ID="ImgProduct" runat="server" ondatabinding="ImgProduct_DataBinding" />
```

in the cs file use this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImgProduct.DataBind();

}
protected void ImgProduct_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImgProduct.ImageUrl = "Image pathe + name";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the `<%# .. %>` is applied only during data binding. One solution is to manually call `DataBind()`

Try

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ImgProduct.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `Page.DataBind()` or `Control.DataBind()`. Otherwise the <%# %> blocks will not be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Why do all the databinding stuff just try the below.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        ImgProduct.ImageUrl = FormatImageUrl("10");
    }
}

protected string FormatImageUrl(string s)
{
    return "image"+s;
}
```

I don't understand, what difference does it make for you to databind it or write the code on code behind. Saving a few key strokes??
It would be rather very easy to also watch the Object on Codebehind rather than the Data Binding expression model