# How can I declaratively read app settings from ServiceConfiguration.cscfg?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

Web.Config

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="minimumValue" value="0" />
   <add key="maximumValue" value="1000" />
</appSettings>
```

Web Form

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Error message." ControlToValidate="TextBox" MinimumValue="<%$ appSettings:minimumValue %>" MaximumValue="<%$ appSettings:maximumValue %>" Type="Integer" />
```

App settings in Web.config file are read-only after deployment process.
So I put these settings to ServiceDefinition.csdef and ServiceConfiguration.cscfg files and I can read them via code-behind:

```
RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue
```

**Does it exists declarative way for this?**

Like <%$ appSettings:maximumValue %> for app setting in Web.Config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it in this way:

```
MinimumValue='<%# System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["minimumValue"] %>'
```

And add this, as it will bind the value to your property:

```
 protected void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

For Details on how this works, check this thread: [how-to-set-contol-property-in-asp-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989544/how-to-set-contol-property-in-asp-net/5989565#5989565)

Comment: Does this work for items which are in the Azure config files - these aren't exposed by `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`?

Comment: IF this <%$ appSettings:minimumValue %> return value in code behind. then in my answer method, it will work. No matter from where you reading the values. But I have told you the way how you can assign value directly.