# What is the use of <%# %>

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

All I know is that `<%# ... %>` is used for binding data to an ASPX page. Is that the only use?

What is the usage of this tag and how it can be used?

Comment: It's new since framework 3.0 as far as I remember, before that we had only `<%= ... %>` and binding from within code behind. This new syntax makes things more simple and add more inline abilities.

Comment: @Samir; Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989544/how-to-set-contol-property-in-asp-net/5989565#5989565

Answer (score 4):

[Data-Binding Expressions Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx) From MSDN.

> Data-binding expressions are contained within <%# and %> delimiters
>   and use the Eval and Bind functions. The Eval function is used to
>   define one-way (read-only) binding. The Bind function is used for
>   two-way (updatable) binding. In addition to calling Eval and Bind
>   methods to perform data binding in a data-binding expression, you can
>   call any publicly scoped code within the <%# and %> delimiters to
>   execute that code and return a value during page processing.

Answer (score 1):

That's its only use.

See here, [Data-Binding Expression Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx.aspx):

> All data-binding expressions must be contained between <%# and %>
>   characters.
>
> ASP.NET supports a hierarchical data-binding model that creates
>   bindings between server control properties and data sources. Almost
>   any server control property can be bound against any public field or
>   property on the containing page or on the server control's immediate
>   naming container.
>
> Data-binding expressions use the Eval and Bind methods to bind data to
>   controls and submit changes back to the database. The Eval method is a
>   static (read-only) method that takes the value of a data field and
>   returns it as a string. The Bind method supports read/write
>   functionality with the ability to retrieve the values of data-bound
>   controls and submit any changes made back to the database.

and here, [Data-Binding Expressions Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx):

> Data-binding expressions are contained within <%# and %> delimiters
>   and use the Eval and Bind functions. The Eval function is used to
>   define one-way (read-only) binding. The Bind function is used for
>   two-way (updatable) binding. In addition to calling Eval and Bind
>   methods to perform data binding in a data-binding expression, you can
>   call any publicly scoped code within the <%# and %> delimiters to
>   execute that code and return a value during page processing.
>
> Data-binding expressions are resolved when the DataBind method of a
>   control or of the Page class is called. For controls such as the
>   GridView, DetailsView, and FormView controls, data-binding expressions
>   are resolved automatically during the control's PreRender event and
>   you are not required to call the DataBind method explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This is an inline tag used for data binding see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx and here http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx for other inline tags.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the only use.

You can use it in the content of any control that supports data binding. It's used to get a value out of one of the items in the data source.

[ASP.NET data binding overview](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860)

Answer (score 0):

There is a MSDN article about DataBinding Expressions on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx but in general are you right. In common you would use it for databinding or data evaluation

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, I copied the quote below from a book to remind me how the <%#%> syntax worked, unfortunately I now can't remember which book I used. Here's the quote anyway -

> Those of you familiar with classic ASP applications might think that the <%#%>syntax looks very familiar. It is similar in purpose, but you need to make sure that you don't confuse the two because doing so could cause your application to function improperly.
> Whereas in ASP (and ASP.NET), the  syntax causes whatever is inside the brackets to be evaluated at render time, the  brackets unique to ASP.NET are evaluated only during binding. As you will see later in this section, the page and each bindable control on the page have a DataBind() method. The expressions contained within the data binding brackets (<%#%>) are evaluated only when the control's DataBind method is invoked.